# Updating location in GPS

Tags: android

Thank you for your time and help in advance. I am working with location using GPS and only I have gotten the current locations and I have tried to update the values of location, but I haven't had any improvement. Can I ask you how could I update the location? The code is below:

activity.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prov"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No provider selected yet"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lat"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Latitude: -"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Longitude: -"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.locationservicetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      TextView latitude;
      TextView longitude;
      TextView provText;
      LocationManager locationManager;
      String provider;
      MyLocationListener mylistener;
      Criteria criteria;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
          longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);
          provText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prov);

          //Get the location manager
          locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);          

          //Define the criteria how to select the location provider
          criteria = new Criteria();
          criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);   //default

          //Charge of data?
          criteria.setCostAllowed(false);

          //Get the best provider depending on the criteria
          provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

          //The last known location of this provider
          Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

          mylistener = new MyLocationListener();

          if (location != null) {
              mylistener.onLocationChanged(location);
          } else {
              //leads to the settings because there is no last known location
              Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
          // location updates: at least 1 meter and 200millsecs change
          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 1, mylistener);
      }

      private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {     
          @Override
          public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Initialize the location fields
              latitude.setText("New Latitude: "+String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
              longitude.setText("New Longitude: "+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
              provText.setText(provider + " provider has been selected.");

              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), provider + "'s status changed to "+status +"!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Provider " + provider + " enabled!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }

          @Override
          public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Provider " + provider + " disabled!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
}
```

I have changed the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.locationservicetest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.locationservicetest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The logcat says:

```
05-20 20:29:40.375: D/ResourcesManager(16834): creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.example.locationservicetest-2/base.apk
05-20 20:29:40.475: D/Activity(16834): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
05-20 20:29:40.475: D/Activity(16834): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
05-20 20:29:40.495: D/OpenGLRenderer(16834): Render dirty regions requested: true
05-20 20:29:40.545: I/Adreno-EGL(16834): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
05-20 20:29:40.545: I/Adreno-EGL(16834): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
05-20 20:29:40.545: I/Adreno-EGL(16834): Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue
05-20 20:29:40.545: I/Adreno-EGL(16834): Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1_RB1_20141028_021_patches2
05-20 20:29:40.545: I/Adreno-EGL(16834): Remote Branch: 
05-20 20:29:40.545: I/Adreno-EGL(16834): Local Patches: 
05-20 20:29:40.545: I/Adreno-EGL(16834): Reconstruct Branch: 
05-20 20:29:40.545: I/OpenGLRenderer(16834): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-20 20:29:40.565: I/OpenGLRenderer(16834): HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0xafb22088 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 8 
05-20 20:29:40.565: D/OpenGLRenderer(16834): Enabling debug mode 0
05-20 20:29:40.655: I/Timeline(16834): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@16c2c9f9 time:221858392
```

I appreciate your guidance, help and time. Thank you.

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried moving to a different location?

Comment: It's good question because this can be a common mistake, but yes, I walk for about one minute without getting any update in my location.

Comment: Are you getting any toast? or anything in logcat? `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, etc.` looks wrong. `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etc.` might work instead.

Comment: I have changed and at the beginning I got a toast saying the "Location changed" However, the values of locations are static.

Comment: What do you mean? You got the toast before the change, or after the change? Please try changing MainActivity.this everywhere.

Comment: After the change I ran the app and at the beginning appeared a toast. I have changed over all the source code.

Comment: Ok, what does logcat say?

Comment: That's not what I meant please replace ***MainActivity.this.getBaseContext()*** with ***getBaseContext()***

Comment: I just ran your code exactly as is, and I saw the numbers change many times.  Does it choose GPS or Network for you?  For me it chose GPS, and it worked better when I walked outside.

Comment: That's weird, how was the  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()..?
I only get:
gps provider has been selected

New Latitude:48.46112125
New Longitude: -123.31152826

And the number doesn't change

Comment: It chose GPS, let me go out because I am in the University.

Comment: Sorry about this, outside its working the app, only that here I didn't get good GPS signal. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ArturoReyesLopez Also, just to note I used the original code you posted before the edit.  So, your code was fine right from the start!

Comment: for testing, you can use a gps faker like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en but just remember to do real-world performance testing later